# Is there a way to insert Log base-something into Google Calculator?

Tags: logarithms, calculator

All I know is that I can do `log(number)` to get log base ten and `ln(number)` to get log base `e`. How can I insert logarithms with other bases in Google Calculator? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: you can use $\log_a b = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$

Comment: @Jane That's probably as complete an answer as is possible for this question, so perhaps it's worth promoting it from a comment to an answer?

Comment: Nice math! Good to know, but is there a more direct route?

Comment: The [Google Guide Quick Reference](http://www.googleguide.com/help/calculator.html) says that `lg` for $log_2$ is available in addition to `log` and `ln`, but those are the only ones.

Comment: @Travis that's ok! at least it's helpful :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For base $b=10$ we can use  `log_10(n)` or `log(n)`

For base $b=e$ we can use `ln(n)`

For base $b=2$ we can use `log_2(n)` or `lg(n)`

Other bases [aren't implemented](http://www.googleguide.com/help/calculator.html), so we use the [Change of Base Rule](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm), namely $\log_b(n) = \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(b)}$ which we put into the calculator as `ln(n)/ln(b)`. This works with any other base, so `log(n)/log(b)` would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Google calculator now supports arbitrary bases. For $\log_2(16)$, for example, you may now enter `log2(16)`.

[Screenshot of Google calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfHTs.png)

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrary bases. `log8(4)` is interpreted as `log(8) * 4`

Comment: @aaron You are right. Apologies, I assumed this would work for any base; appears to only work for base 2.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+calculator+log243%281000 apparently only for some numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can input it into the Google search bar like this, log_base(x) would be written as:

log(x,base)

For example, log base 11 of 4 (or log_11(4) ) would look like this:

log(4,11)

As for Google calculator... not sure yet.

Comment: This is wrong. Google treats the comma as a decimal point here. You can tell because `log(4,0)` is equal to `log(4)`.